# How is "foo" different from foo, in a mongodb key:value pair?

Tags: mongodb

When I see a field:value pair as

`"name":"foo"` and `"name":foo`

what is the difference between the two? Are both the values supposed to be strings?

And what about

`"age":3` and `"age":"3"`

Is the first one an integer? I am confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Strings vs. variables

The following assigns the **string value** `"foo"` to a property:

```
item = { "name" : "foo" } // item.name = "foo"
```

The following assigns the value of the `foo` **variable** to a property. If the `foo` variable doesn't exist, you'll receive an error message:

```
item = { "name" : foo } // foo doesn't exist yet, will result in error

foo = "my value" // foo is defined here
item = { "name" : foo } // item.name = "my value"
```

#### Numbers vs. strings

The following assigns a **[`Number`](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp) value** to a property:

```
child = { "age" : 3 } // child.age = 3
```

Numbers can be used in *all* mathematical operations. For example, `child.age * 3` will result in 9 and `child.age + 4` will result in 7.

The following assigns a **string value** to a property:

```
child = { "age" : "3" } // child.age = "3"
```

Strings cannot be used in all calculations. For example, `child.age * 3` will result in 9, **but** `child.age + 4` will result in 34, due to string concatenation.

You should only use strings if the data is textual data. If the data is numerical, store it as a number (without the quotes).

Comment: One thing to note unless it has been changed, numbers started with a ZERO has to be surrounded in quotes. With zipcodes, I was forced to throw my values in the collection as "08010." If i tried doing so w/o the quotes, the leading zero gets cut off.

Comment: @luckytaxi: Technically, zip codes aren't numbers, but codes ;) But you do point out an important aspect of number in JavaScript: numbers starting with a zero are treated as **octal numbers**. So if you enter 012, you'll end up with 10 instead of the 'expected' 12.